# laravel 8 submit following data would have been submitted to the server

Tags: laravel, error-handling, popupwindow

**Its work yesterday day I didn't do any changes but today but unh?**

**problem is  : when ever from submit button is click its open a popup and show error message**

here is the blade file code

```xml
<div class="box">
    <div class="box-header with-border">
        <h3 class="box-title">Add Brand</h3>
    </div>
    <!-- /.box-header -->
    <div class="box-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <form method="POST" action="{{route('barnd.store')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf
                <div class="form-group">
                    <h5>Brand name English <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" name="brand_name_eng" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    @error('brand_name_eng')
                        <span class="text text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                    @enderror
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <h5>Brand name German <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" name="brand_name_gem" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    @error('brand_name_gem')
                        <span class="text text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                    @enderror
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <h5>Brand Image <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    @error('image')
                        <span class="text text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                    @enderror
                </div>
                <div class="text-xs-right" style="float: right;">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-rounded btn-primary">Update</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.box-body -->
</div>
```

here is my controller with just simple validation

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validated = $request->validate([
        'brand_name_eng' => 'required',
        'brand_name_gem' => 'required',
        'image' => 'required',
    ]);
}
```

then I try to test this but in the view I click just update button I got this
[image]

i have no idea why suddenly I am getting this kind of error

NOTE: and I enable log there no log as well

how can I solve this? and where its come from this error?

Comment: check the JS in your browser and backtrace the condition of that alert

Answer (score 1):

You can Die and Dump your request() to see if your request is getting to your server or not!

If not solved check the mass assignment functionality on your model.

Comment: even the request not pass to the post method its block in the frontend

Comment: All right, I think its something wrong with your "forms action". 
You can go for different approaches. First, write your
`action="/brand/store"`
Create a route as 
`Route::post('brand/store',[BrandController::class,'store']);`
 and Finally Your Controller 'code' 
`public function store() { 
dd(request); 
 } `
Check if everything is okay or not

Comment: hi still same error